# Flask webserver in Heroku returning 404 when serving CSS files

Tags: flask, heroku

Website works for everything except CSS files. Static images works, static javascript works, favicon works, but CSS returns 404. I've tried different browsers and cache-reload on web browser.

Application logs:

```
2021-08-04T15:17:38.416574+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
path="/static/css/index.css" host=redacted fwd="82.196.112.61"
dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=2332 protocol=https

2021-08-04T15:17:38.424598+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
path="/static/js/bootstrap.bundle.js" host=redacted fwd="82.196.112.61"
dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=27ms status=200 bytes=208248 protocol=https
```

This is my project structure. It works fully well locally, but as soon as I push it to Heroku the CSS fails to be served.

Project structure:

[image: Project structure]

App.py:

```
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',
            port=33507,
            use_reloader = True)
```

__init__.py:

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
from whitenoise import WhiteNoise
app = Flask(__name__)

# Allows the app to identify the static folder
app.static_folder = 'static'
app.wsgi_app = WhiteNoise(
    app.wsgi_app,
    root='static/')

@app.route("/static/<path:path>")
def static_dir(path):
    return send_from_directory("static", path)

#Configuration of application, see configuration.py, choose one and uncomment.
configuration = 'app.configuration.ProductionConfig'
#configuration = 'app.configuration.DevelopmentConfig'
app.config.from_object(configuration)
print('Running server on ' + app.config['ENV'] + '.')

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
print('Running database at', app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])

from app import views, models

db.create_all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The issue was rooted in heroku being case-sensitive while Github is not. Even though you change the case on a folder locally, it does not get commited and pushed to Github, and this then propagates to Heroku.

**TL;DR: Check that your folders are persistent in it's letter case, locally, on Github, and in Heroku.**

Github:

[image]

Code:

[image]

[image]